# Swift get return value from closure and use it to return from closure that it's inside of

Tags: swift

Consider the following:

```
func myClosure(_ my_object: MyObject, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    var bool: Bool
    ...
    completion(bool)
}

let my_filtered_objects = my_objects.filter { obj in
    myClosure(obj.id) { bool in
        return bool // doesn't return from the filter closure
    }
    return true // returns from the filter closure
}
```

The closure from the function `myClosure` captures a `Bool` which I've called `bool`, and I would like to use `bool` to return from the closure in `filter`. What I've put returns `bool` within the scope of `myClosure`, but the closure in `filter` knows nothing of it. How can I achieve the desired effect of returning `bool` from `filter`'s closure? Thanks.

Comment: what type is `myClosure`?

Comment: @HaydenHolligan I've updated my answer.

Comment: To clarify, you want to use your closure as the predicate for the filter?

Comment: I don't think that it will work, at least without using dispatch group. Try to use dispatch to wait until closure inside that filter will become completed. So in the filter closure create a Boolean variable, create a dispatch group to wait a completion, update that variable and then make return

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If the closure is non-escaping, this is easy:

```
let my_filtered_objects = my_objects.filter { obj in
    var retVal = false
    myClosure(obj.id) { bool in
        retVal = bool
    }
    return retVal
}
```

For an escaping closure, you may need to use a semaphore to make sure the closure has finished by the time your function returns:

```
let my_filtered_objects = my_objects.filter { obj in
    var retVal = false
    let semaphore = DispathchSemaphore(value: 0)

    myClosure(obj.id) { bool in
        retVal = bool
        semaphore.signal()
    }

    semaphore.wait()

    return retVal
}
```

As @Woof said, though, using a dispatch group to do this asynchronously may be better-performing.